# WP8.1 XAML - how to get a GridView item to show when it is selected?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to get the selected item in a GridView (Windows Phone 8.1 C#/XAML app) to be highlighted. I've extracted the GridViewItemStyle using Blend and it contains the following:

```
<Border x:Name="SelectedBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMultiselectBorderThickness}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">
    <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="34" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34">
        <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Path x:Name="SelectedGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="14.5" Margin="0,1,1,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I've defined the brush colours used by this XAML and temporarily set the opacity to 1 so that I can check it should be displaying. So far, so good.

There is also a visual state group in the same style definition:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

but when an item is selected, it doesn't gain the visual indicator. The XAML that displays the indicator is clearly working so I'm trying to understand why the visual state group isn't, particularly since this came straight out of Blend.

The GridView definition is as follows:

```
<GridView 
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListViewSection2"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding GroupMembers}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Individual80ItemTemplate}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle1}"
    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True"
    SelectionChanged="itemView_SelectionChanged"
    Loaded="itemGridView_Loaded"/>
```

**Update**: If I change SelectionMode from Single to Multiple, the good thing is that the SelectedEarmark and SelectedGlyph now appear as each item is selected ... the bad thing, though, is that the SelectedBorder is made visible for all of the entries which seems to be triggered by another bit of Visual State stuffery:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiSelectStates">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualTransition From="ListMultiSelect" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="NoMultiSelect"/>
        <VisualTransition From="NoMultiSelect" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="ListMultiSelect"/>
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualState x:Name="NoMultiSelect"/>
    <VisualState x:Name="ListMultiSelect">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckboxContainerTranslateTransform"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTranslateX}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorderTranslateTransform"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="GridMultiSelect">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

The only way I seem to be able to work around this is either by removing those visual states from the style or by altering the border XAML so it basically doesn't draw the border. The shame of **that** is that I can't use the built-in style; I've basically got to provide my own style. I suppose, on reflection, that probably isn't such a bad thing ... once you get the hang of figuring out how the item styles work, along with setters, etc.

Comment: Where did you define the brushes?

Comment: For selectionmode="single" SelectedEarmark and SelectedGlyph are not in frame. Change it to selection mode multiple to see if its in frame

Comment: Thanks, @ChiragShah, for that suggestion. I've updated the question with the outcome of that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FocusStates instead of SelectionStates.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
     <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration = "0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration = "0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration = "1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration = "1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
```

Hope this will work. If not then you can define your own Custom States and use it in code behind.

I had the same problem. See my question and answer for reference.
[Custom Selection States](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983452/uwp-visualstates-selectionstates-selected-and-unselected-is-not-working-in-l/36010296?noredirect=1#comment59752019_36010296)

Comment: I ended up using custom states, in a similar form to your linked question and answer. I couldn't get focus states to work - it may not be supported on Windows Phone 8.1. Thanks for the link, though - that helped a lot.

Comment: Glade it helped. And No Worries if the VisualStates not work in XAML, Just use it in SelectionChanged Event in code behind as mentioned in given Link. And in the same manner you can use as many as you can the Custom VisualStates and apply it to Style inside. Its perfectly work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the listviewitem style which I tweaked to get the desired result.

```
<Style x:Key="MyListViewItemStyle"
           TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation"
                Value="Local" />
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled"
                Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMargin}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Border x:Name="OuterContainer"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Margin="0,5,0,5"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform" />
                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed"
                                                      To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckboxPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckboxTiltContainer" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiSelectStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="ListMultiSelect"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15"
                                                      To="NoMultiSelect" />
                                    <VisualTransition From="NoMultiSelect"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15"
                                                      To="ListMultiSelect" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoMultiSelect" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="ListMultiSelect">
                                    <Storyboard></Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="GridMultiSelect">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderModeStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="ReorderEnabled"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2"
                                                      To="ReorderDisabled" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReorderEnabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterContainer" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Reorderable">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.075"
                                                                  Value="1.05" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2"
                                                                  Value="1.0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.075"
                                                                  Value="1.05" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2"
                                                                  Value="1.0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReorderDisabled" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"
                                                      To="NoReorderHint" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom"
                                                                ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right"
                                                                ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top"
                                                                ToOffset="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left"
                                                                ToOffset="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent"
                              Background="Transparent">
                            <Border x:Name="CheckboxTiltContainer"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Margin="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMultiselectCheckBoxMargin}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Border x:Name="CheckboxOuterContainer">
                                    <Border.Clip>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,25.5,25.5" />
                                    </Border.Clip>
                                    <Grid x:Name="CheckboxContainer">
                                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="CheckboxContainerTranslateTransform"
                                                                X="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentOffsetX}" />
                                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle"
                                                   Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                                   Height="25.5"
                                                   Stroke="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeBrush}"
                                                   StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}"
                                                   Width="25.5" />
                                        <Path x:Name="CheckGlyph"
                                              Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z"
                                              Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                              FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              Height="17"
                                              IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                              Opacity="0"
                                              Stretch="Fill"
                                              StrokeThickness="2.5"
                                              StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              Width="18.5" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                                <Border x:Name="TiltContainer">
                                    <Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentBorderTranslateTransform" />
                                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
                                                       AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                                       Foreground="{x:Null}"
                                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                                       Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                       Opacity="0"
                                                       Text="Xg" />
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect"
                                                       Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                                       Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="SelectedBorder"
                                    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMultiselectBorderThickness}"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    Opacity="0">
                                <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                      Height="34"
                                      Opacity="0"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                      Width="34">
                                    <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark"
                                          Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z"
                                          Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                          Stretch="Fill" />
                                    <Path x:Name="SelectedGlyph"
                                          Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z"
                                          Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}"
                                          FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                          Height="14.5"
                                          Margin="0,1,1,0"
                                          Stretch="Fill"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                          Width="17" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. I would appreciate editing the criticism in the question if the above code helps :)

Comment: I didn't imply any criticism of your suggestion or feedback - it was a criticism of the platform. I ended up actually using quite a stripped down item style in the end. For my particular use case, I didn't need a lot of the bits that came with the default style, but I appreciate your assistance as it has helped me better understand how this works.

Comment: I was referring to the platform's criticism you made, I know its a little too restrictive but its still coming good. Even though its personal opinion,but such remarks would have a negative impact on any new  developer.